# Legend title position in ggplot2

Tags: r, position, ggplot2, legend

Anone know how to change the position of the legend title in ggplot?

I have used the following code to move the legend to the bottom and make it horizontal

```
p <- p + opts(legend.position = 'bottom', legend.direction = 'horizontal')
```

But **now I want the title to be to the left of the legend instead of above**. I've looked in the follwing places but cant find it or figure it out:

https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes
http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/book/toolbox.r

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 30):

Using the [transition guide](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf) to version 0.9 as a reference, you might try the following (assuming you want to change the title position for the `colour` legend):

```
library(scales)
+ guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "left"))
```

For a continuous scale you'd use `guide_colorbar` instead of `guide_legend`.

Just to provide a concrete example to prove I'm not just making this up,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point(aes(colour = qsec)) + 
    guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "right"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the transition guide looks like a great reference.  Unfortulatly your suggestion didnt work.  Curiously, I get the following error:

Comment: > p <- p + guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "left"))
Error: could not find function "guides".  Do you know if I have to reload ggplot2 to get version 0.9?

Comment: @MikeTP Sorry, I keep forgetting to tell people to load **scales**, `library(scales)`.

Comment: @MikeTP And yes, this will only work with version 0.9, so if you still have 0.8.9, you'll have to reinstall ggplot2.

Comment: Thank Joran, dumb follow up question, how do I update to version 0.9.  When I try to simply install ggplot2 again I still get version 0.8.9?

Comment: @MikeTP I'm guessing that you would need to update R. ggplot2 0.9.0 requires 2.14.1 or higher. If you have an older version than that, then 0.8.9 is the last available version.

Comment: is there a way to rotate the legend title by 90 degrees?

Comment: @yuliaUU Maybe you're looking for `theme(legend.direction = "horizontal")`?