# How can I place the legend title on top of the labels when the legend position is, for example, bottom?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Example:

```
xy <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1, type = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=5))

plot <- ggplot(data = xy)+
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color=type)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom')

plot
```

How can we get the title 'type' on top of A and B, not to their left?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can get rid of your problem using guides() and specifying title position.

```
library(ggplot2)
xy <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=10:1, type = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=5))

plot <- ggplot(data = xy)+ geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, color=type)) +
        theme(legend.position = 'bottom') + 
        guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "top"))

plot
```

Although this is old, I noticed that this answer
[Legend title position in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739947/legend-title-position-in-ggplot2) is good yet, even if ggplot2 is now many versions above 0.9.
I noticed that is not necessary anymore the call to library(scales).
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I knew how to do it with opts, which has been deprecated for a while. I couldn't figure out that the positioning is determined within colour